# Content Click Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to count the number of clicks on a piece of content - after which, I need to run a certain function.
I can't run the function on *every* click, only after the user finishes their desired clicks.

The amount of clicks needs to be 1, 2, or 3 and above, where I only want to do something on one or two clicks, and ignore anything else.

**Note** I only need to run the function *after* the clicks, then reset the counter.

I've tried the following, but it logs 'single' after every click.

```
        var clicks = 0;

        $(controller).click(function() {
            var elem = this, $elem = jQuery(elem), clicks = $elem.data('clicks') || 0;
            clicks += 1;

            // Reset triple click counter if no click is made within 500ms
            setTimeout(function() {
                clicks = 0;
            }, 500);

            setTimeout(function() {
                if (clicks >= 3) {
                    console.log("triple or more");
                }
                if (clicks === 2) {
                    console.log("double");
                }
                if (clicks === 1) {
                    console.log("single");
                }
            }, 200);

        });
```

[Here is a JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/tanubitemacu/1/)

Comment: In you JSBin code clicks is declared as click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to see what you want to happen after 3 clicks, do you want to trigger triple clicks for each of them or not.

I created a version that you might want to look at: http://jsbin.com/dutilojujowa/5/edit

The ideas are:

1. Save all the click counter data into the data attribute instead of relying on scope - I find that easier.
2. Throttle your reset counter, otherwise multiple clicks can be handled very strangely
3. Throttle your action counter, or you might get multiple actions accidentally!
4. Make sure you set $elem.data('clicks') to 1 at some point, or it won't work.

Comment: This actually looks really promising - However it first displays 'double' as it get to triple - this means the code will still run on a triple click - any way to sort that out?

Comment: @SemiDemented Oops! See updated at http://jsbin.com/dutilojujowa/5/edit - I forgot to throttle the action as well as the reset :D

Comment: Any idea why my controller will be registering two clicks when I only clicked once? Like its doubling up on running the click event.

Comment: Additionally, `$._data( $(controller)[0], "events" )` shows two click events

Comment: **Update:** `$(controller).unbind('click').unbind('mouseup').click()` is a hacky but working fix

Comment: Yeah I would have guessed that the binding had been done twice. No clue why, I would have to dig around the site a bit more to have any better answers, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `$elem.data('clicks')` at the end of your function. See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/triple-click-event/

Comment: Updated my question - it is defined outside the click scope

Comment: This, or you need to write the new value back into the external data source.

Comment: I've tried creating the custom triple click handler - however extending it to include 1 or 2 clicks in the end resets the counter before a triple can be declared. This means three 'single' again

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code:

```
var totalCount;
    var intervalVar;
    var ShowResultVar;
    function HandleClicks() {
        totalCount = totalCount + 1;
    }

    function ShowResult() {
        if(totalCount == 0)
        {
            console.log("No Clicks");
        }
        else if (totalCount == 1)
        {
            console.log("One Click");
        }
        else if(totalCount == 2)
        {
            console.log("Two Clicks");
        }
        else if (totalCount >2) {
            console.log("Three or more Clicks");
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        totalCount = 0;
        $("#myControl").bind("click", HandleClicks);
        intervalVar = setInterval(function () {
            totalCount = 0;
        }, 500);
        ShowResultVar = setInterval(function () {
            ShowResult();
        }, 200);
    });
```

It is working for me. Output is as follows:

```
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 One Click 
 Two Clicks 
 One Click 
 Two Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 One Click 
 Two Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 One Click 
 Two Clicks 
 Two Clicks 
 Three or more Clicks 
 One Click 
 One Click 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks 
 No Clicks
```

Comment: This never resets. Also its doing something on every click, not at the end of the users clicks.

Comment: When you triple click, does it still show 'Two Clicks' >

Comment: No it is showing me Three or more clicks..I am checking for totalCount > 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
   $("#content").data('clicks', 0);
$("#content").click(function () {
    var elem = this,
        $elem = jQuery(elem);
    var clicks = $elem.data('clicks') + 1
    $elem.data('clicks', clicks);
    if (clicks == 1) {//start re-setter and counter when first click 
        setTimeout(function () {
            $elem.data('clicks', 0);
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var clicks = $elem.data('clicks');
            if (clicks >= 3) {
                console.log("triple or more");
            }
            if (clicks === 2) {
                console.log("double");
            }
            if (clicks === 1) {
                console.log("single");
            }
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/2d6pwhL6/2/)